# delete[] Array of characters

Tags: c++, memory, new-operator, delete-operator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [delete[] supplied a modified new-ed pointer. Undefined Behaviour?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/788482/delete-supplied-a-modified-new-ed-pointer-undefined-behaviour)

Let's say I've allocated a handful of characters using `new char[number]`.

Will it be possible to delete only a few end characters (something like `delete[] (charArray + 4);`, which will supposedly de-allocate all of characters except for the first four)?

I read that some implementations' `new[]` store the number of objects allocated before the array of objects so that `delete[]` knows how many objects to de-allocate, so it's probably unsafe to do what I'm asking...

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

Is manually deleting the unwanted end bytes using separate `delete` statements a safe way to do what I'm asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only "safe" way to do it is to allocate a new array, copy the data, and delete the old one. Or you could just follow the `std::vector` way and differentiate between "capacity" (the size of the array) and "size" (the amount of elements in it).

Comment: Could you explain a little more on the way `std::vector` does it?

Comment: @myrkos It allocates space to store *n* elements, but it might report its size as *<= n*.  This is to make resizing more efficient.

Comment: @myrkos: It allocates "raw" space with `::operator new`, and then uses placement `new` to turn that raw space into objects. When it needs to destroy objects (e.g., when the `vector` goes out of scope or you `erase` elements) it invokes the dtor directly to do so.

Answer (score 6):

No, you have to `delete[]` exactly the same pointer you get back with `new[]`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't delete a specific segment of an array.

If you're just operating on C strings, you can set a character to `\0` and any functions that operate on the string will stop there, as C strings are null-terminated.

If you actually need to free up that memory, the closest you can get would be to make a new, smaller array, copy the elements over, and `delete[]` the old array.

```
char* TenCharactersLong = new char[10];
// ...
char* FirstFiveCharacters = new char[5];
for (std::size_t Index = 0; Index < 5; Index++)
{
    FirstFiveCharacters[Index] = TenCharactersLong[Index];
}
delete[] TenCharactersLong;
```

Answer (score 1):

Nope, sorry. Memory allocation is complex enough with fragmentation, alignment, padding, overheads, whatnot. A feature like this would only further amplify these problems.

> Is manually deleting the unwanted end bytes using separate delete statements a safe way to do what I'm asking?

Don't even try. This can be dangerous. Always deallocate arrays with delete [].

I highly recommend reading the C++ FAQ Lite on this topic: [16.13](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/freestore-mgmt.html#faq-16.13), [16.14](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/freestore-mgmt.html#faq-16.14)

Answer (score 0):

No, you can only delete the *entire* array.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do that.  I'd suggest using an std::vector for this.  This way you can pinpoint the indexes that you want to remove and just let the libraries handle it for you.